# what is the alternative for Provider Class to use in j2me

Tags: java, java-me, provider, jce

can anyone please tell me how to use jce in J2ME ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [bouncycastle](http://www.bouncycastle.org/latest_releases.html). And see this [example](http://www.java-tips.org/java-me-tips/midp/encrypting-decrypting-text-messages-with-bouncy-castle-crypt.html).